# Add and removing value to object javascript

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a function

```js
function Player(name,gold,exp){
  this.name = name;
  this.gold = gold;
  this.exp = exp;
}
```

and I call

`var player1 = new Player('James',100,0);`

Now `player` has a name,gold amount, and exp amount but later in my game I also have diamonds so how would I add diamonds to the `player1` object

**Bonus:**

Lets say I wanna replace the gold currency with the diamonds currency how would I remove gold from the `player1` object

**Preferences:**

If possible I would like to functionalize(is that a word? It should be!) everything for example if I could add something I would like functions like

***BELOW IS NOT ACTUAL CODE IT IS JUST A REPRESENTATION OF WHAT I WOULD PREFER AND IS MORE THEN LIKELY NOT EVEN CLOSE TO ANYTHING***

```js
//Add function
function Add(object,addName,addValue){
  this.object.addName = addValue;
}

//Remove function

function Remove(object,removeName){
  this.object.removeName = destroy;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Add function
function Add(obj, addName, addValue) {
  obj[addName] = addValue;
}

// Remove function
function Remove(obj, removeName) {
  delete obj[removeName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete` to remove a property from an object

```
delete player1.gold
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any function:

```js
function Player(name, gold, exp){
  this.name = name;
  this.gold = gold;
  this.exp = exp;
}

var player1 = new Player('James', 100, 0);

player1.diamond = 3; //add
console.log(player1.diamond);

delete player1.gold; //delete
console.log(player1.gold);
```